# Iterative process to return second lowest value

Tags: .net, vb.net, iteration, nearest-neighbor

I am fairly new to vb.net and cannot find any specific help after several hours of searching.

I have a table of data points with three columns, column 1 is the "point id", column 2 is the "x co-ordinate" and column 3 is the "y co-ordinate". I need to add a fourth column and then populate this with the second lowest value from an iterative process.

The iterative process is finding the distance from that point to each other point an returning the second lowest value as the lowest value would be 0 (distance to itself). The maths for the distance between point 1 and point 2 is sqrt(((x2-x1)*(x2-x1))+((y2-y1)*(y2-y1))).

I am strugling to do an iterative process within an iterative process in order to retun a single value.

Any help would be greatly apprecited :)

Comment: Do you have any codes so far? or nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the rows in your table. Then for each row iterate again through the rows in your table. But when you reach the row your primary iteration currently is on, you can skip that one and move on. Also, since distances are between pairs of points, you should only need to iterate through half of the rows in your table to get all the distances.

If you post some more details about how exactly your are implementing this it might be possible to help you out with some code, but as it is now, you don't even say what kind of table you have or how your program is set up, so it's difficult to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution [untested]. The `AddNearestColumn()` method loops through each row and gets a List of distances to the other points in the table. It then loops through the list and gets the smallest value. You should use `distances.Sort()` in `AddNearestColumn()`  rather than looping manually, but I'll leave that for you. :-)

```
Public Sub ProcessTable(table As Data.DataTable)
    AddNearestColumn(table)
End Sub

Private Sub AddNearestColumn(table As Data.DataTable)
    table.Columns.Add("Nearest", GetType(Double))
    For Each r As Data.DataRow In table.Rows
        Dim distances As List(Of Double) = GetDistancesFromPoint(table, r)
        Dim nearest As Double = Double.MaxValue
        For Each distance As Double In distances
            If (distance < nearest) Then nearest = distance
        Next
        r.Item("Nearest") = nearest
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetDistancesFromPoint(table As Data.DataTable, referenceRow As Data.DataRow) As List(Of Double)
    Dim output As New List(Of Double)
    For Each r As Data.DataRow In table.Rows
        Dim referenceId As String = CStr(referenceRow.Item("ID"))
        Dim rowId As String = CStr(r.Item("ID"))
        If (rowId = referenceId) Then Continue For
        Dim x1 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(referenceRow.Item("X"))
        Dim y1 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(referenceRow.Item("Y"))
        Dim x2 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(r.Item("X"))
        Dim y2 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(r.Item("Y"))
        output.Add(Math.Sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1))))
    Next
    Return output
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have tried to put this code into my existing code but get the error "Value of type 'System.Data.Datarow' cannot be converted to Integer." I noticed in your code that r is not "dim"ed anywhere, is this the reason for the error?

Comment: I banged out my original answer in Notepad and had mistakenly put `.Value` at the end of each `Item`. See updated code.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain again, the code runs ok unil it gets to the point "dim x2 as double" i get an error of "object cannot be cast from DBNull o other types". Any ideas?

Comment: No problem. I see you are new to this :-).  Most of the code you will see on StackOverflow is short and to the point - no error handling, argument checking, etc. This make it easy to read. It's expected that you will add all that junk in "real" code. Anyway, your DBNull error is because the field is NULL, and .NET can't convert that to a Double.  You need to check for NULL prior to each `.Item()` reference. Most people write a helper function for this.  If Item().Equals(DBNull.Value) then return 0 Else Return CDouble(Item())...